# iphone web form validation

Tags: javascript, iphone, validation

I have this form for a dedicated iphone landing page. but cant find anything that will deal with the validation. i only need to validate the number but the name could also be usefull. i cant seem to find anything that will alert the user the field has not been entered.

this is iphone only and is a web form not a app

```
<form method="post" action="submitquote.php" name="quoteform">
<label>Your Full Name</label>
<input style="outline:none;" id="name" type="text" name="name" size="20" value="" class="elements"/>
<label>Your Email Address</label>
<input style="outline:none;" id="email" type="email" name="email" size="20" value="" class="elements"/>
<label>Your Telephone Number</label>
<input style="outline:none;" id="telephone" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="telephone" size="20" value="" class="elements">            
<label>Company Postcode</label>
<input style="outline:none;" id="postcode" type="text" name="postcode" size="20" value="" class="input" /> 

<div class="saveon">Save on..</div>

<div class="checkboxs">Gas<input type="hidden" name="gasresult" value="no" /><input name="gasresult" type="checkbox" value="yes" checked="checked" /> Electricity<input type="hidden" name="electricresult" value="no" /><input name="electricresult" type="checkbox" value="yes" checked="checked" /></div>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $myid ?>" name="track" />
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['utm_source']; ?>" name="utm_source" />
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['utm_medium']; ?>" name="utm_medium" />
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['utm_term']; ?>" name="utm_term" />
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['utm_content']; ?>" name="utm_content" />
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['utm_campaign']; ?>" name="utm_campaign" />
<input type="submit" value="" class="submit" onclick="pageTracker._trackPageview('/HomePage/ClassicQuoteRequest/Submit')" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to get the value of an input object of a form.

```
function nameOK() {
    var myForm = document.quoteform; // document.#nameOfForm#
    var input = myForm.name;
    var content = input.value;
    return (content != "");
}
```

It is untested, but I have recently done something similar to store cookies.

Hope it works,
ief2